# No Port Parameter in Send-MailMessage when trying to send mail to Office 365?

Tags: email, powershell, parameters

Here is the version of Powershell I'm using:

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion yields:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Here is the command:

```
Send-MailMessage -To "someadmin@somedomain.com" -Body "This is just a test"  -Subject "Test"  -UseSsl
 -Port 587 -SmtpServer 'smtp.office365.com' -From 'someadmin@somedomain.com' -Credential $creds
```

Here is the error:

```
Send-MailMessage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Port'.
At line:1 char:105
+ Send-MailMessage -To "someadmin@somedomain.com" -Body "This is just a test"  -Subject "Test"  -UseSsl -Port <<<<  587 -S
mtpServer 'smtp.office365.com' -From 'someadmin@somedomain.com' -Credential $creds
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Was the `Port` argument something in that version of Powershell?  Do I need to upgrade powershell to use this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the `-Port` Parameter is available from Powershell 3.0 upwards only.

Source: [Microsoft Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx)

Comment: The default version of PowerShell in Windows 7 is not Powershell 3.0.
(in Windows 8 is Powershell 3.)
The download page of the Powershell 3.0 is https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595